# CentOS Host KVM Virtual Machine running a Windows VM - No internet access

Tags: networking, centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I've installed a KVM virtual machine on a CentOS host using libvirt. I've also set up a bridged connection from the interface `en0:4` running on IP x.x.x.15 to `br0`. (The IP is a public one).

Running `ifconfig` outputs:

```
root@<snip> [~]# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:x.x.x.15  Bcast:x.x.x.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: <ipv6-snip> Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7505092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3991863 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4762161595 (4.4 GiB)  TX bytes:610257080 (581.9 MiB)
```

I've removed the `en0` entries.

As far as I can tell, the above is set up correctly(?). However, in my windows VM, it shows 'Limited Connectivity', and it has assigned itself a 169.x.x.x address. I've tried setting the static IP information to that shown on the bridge connection, but still 'limited connectivity' shows up.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `en0:4`? That sounds wrong. Exactly how did you configure this bridge?

Comment: I ran `virsh iface-bridge eth0:4 br0`

Comment: There are multiple IP's bound to `eth0` which I think is why they're split the way they are. It's managed by cPanel though, I haven't set it up